# No way to reach breakpoints debugging my iOS app

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am at the moment working on launching my App on iOS.
My application is working well on android and uwp (all breakpoints are ok).
But when I launch my application on iOS I reach breakpoints thar are in App.Mobile.Ios but not in the global project App.Mobile, containing for example my login code.
Is it a normal behaviour? did I miss something or it's a known bug?

Thank you

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to say without any code examples and further information. Are you using Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Yes, I'm using xamarin forms. I think it's not a code issue as my UWP and android projects are working perfectly with breakpoints. In my Ios project I'm reaching the common code as the good pages are loading but no way to reach a breakpoint in the common code..

Answer (score 0):

This can occur if the PCL common project is not being built at the same time the iOS app is being built. Look in your Configuration Manager(Visual Studio) [1] or your Configuration Mappings (Xamarin Studio) [2] and make sure that both the PCL and the iOS project are selected to build for the configuration you are building against.

[1] To open the configuration Manager in VS, click on the arrow for the drop down to select a configuration and select "Configuration Manager". Make sure that the PCL and iOS projects a selected to build.

[2] To open the configuration Manager in XS, right click on the solution in the Solution Explorer and select "Options". Then select Build->Configurations->Configuration Mappings tab. Make sure that the PCL and iOS projects a selected to build.

Comment: I checked it and the two projects are built (it's a sure thing as I pass in my code in the PCL project) But when passing to a break point there is no pause at all

Answer (score 0):

I guess it was a bug on this version of xamarin, the new update solved the problem